# Spring Boot JPA with MySQL Docker container - Access denied to user

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have a very basic Spring Boot app that I aim to use JPA/MySQL:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

However, my MySQL database is a Docker container:

```
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass123 -d mysql:8.0.1
```

Below is my application.properties file to configure the DB connection:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

I've set up my database and user like so:

```
> docker exec -it mysql bash -l
root@cef13b77d8c6:/# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 8.0.1-dmr MySQL Community Server (GPL)
...
mysql> create database db_example;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> create user 'springuser'@'%' identified by 'ThePassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> grant all on db_example.* to 'springuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
```

Ready... :)

When I run the JAR I get `Access denied to user 'springuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`:

```
> mvn clean package
...
> java -jar .\target\accessing-data-mysql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
2019-12-19 11:28:29.659  INFO 42768 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-12-19 11:28:29.685  INFO 42768 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-19 11:28:29.686  INFO 42768 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-12-19 11:28:29.783  INFO 42768 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-19 11:28:29.783  INFO 42768 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1424 ms
2019-12-19 11:28:29.926  INFO 42768 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-12-19 11:28:31.512 ERROR 42768 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'springuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
...
```

I can access the database with this user:

```
> docker exec -it mysql bash -l
root@cef13b77d8c6:/# mysql -uspringuser -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 8.0.1-dmr MySQL Community Server (GPL)
...
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| db_example         |
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So seems my user exists and can access the database that way, just not from the Spring Boot app. Is there anything I've missed? I'm not sure if the fact I'm trying to connect to MySQL on a Docker container requires additional configuration in the Spring Boot app over and above what the tutorial I'm following suggests, or whether I need to make my container more "visible" when instantiating it... any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't exposed mysql container to docker host. Add `-p 3306:3306` on your docker run command.

Comment: Right, that totally makes sense. Actually I've added `-p 33067:3306` as my host's 3306 is in use with a local MySQL but I'm keen on this Docker approach. I've updated my application.properties file also to `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:33067/db_example`. Seems working now, thanks.